# how to multiply two arrays with different sizes in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to do my homework but what I am trying does not work.

the assignment is to basically multiply 2 arrays of different sizes together( and put all three into a message box so if you could help me with as well that would be great)

the problem is that I am getting "overflow" amounts of values, there should only be 10 but I am getting like 28

the code I currently have is

```
double[] array1 = new Double[10] { 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
double[] array2 = new Double[5] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
double[] array3 = new double[10];
int hold = 1;
int counter = 0;
foreach (int c in array1)
{
    foreach(int k in array2)
    {
        if (counter <= k)
        {
            array3[c] = (array1[c] * array2[c]);//edit3: array2 was wirtten with  c when copied th outcome different but still not rigth with k
        }
        else
        {
            array3[c] = (array1[c] * hold);
        }
    }

    foreach (int j in array3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(array3[c]);
    }
}
```

the out come looks like

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
6
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
```

it should look like

```
0
2
6
12
20
6
7
8
9
10
```

**I have check stackoverflow all ready, so please just help not link me to another question, or if you do put a comment with it saying what I need to look at.**

edit: the array3 have j just gives ten 0

edit2: the debugger is telling me what I already know I am making too many 
values, the question is how to fix this, and only make 10 values

Comment: This is a **great** opportunity to learn how to debug your code using the **[free, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: That second for loop inside the first for loop seems a bit out of place. Also, why are you reusing `c` in that loop where you want to iterate `array3`. Also, why foreach, you don't want to have the index (as your code suggest) as opposed to the value? And counter doesn't seem to be increasing in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many mistakes in your code. You need only one loop:

```
double[] array1 = new Double[10] { 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
double[] array2 = new Double[5] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
double[] array3 = new double[10];
int hold = 1;
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
{
        if (i < array2.Length)
        {
            array3[i] = array1[i] * array2[i];
        }
        else
        {
            array3[i] = (array1[i] * hold);
        }
}

foreach (int j in array3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(j);
    }
```

Comment: Fixed didn't bother reading the print function but apparently even that was not correct

Comment: Thank you, that work after fixing the array.Length() problem, the parathesis are not supposed to be there

Comment: Looks better now, as long as `array1` is larger than `array2` :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have to write something that can do a multiplication of two arrays with (possible) different lengths, you could start with determining the longest array from the shortest one, and then iterate the shortest and concatenate the leftover to the resulting array (since that stays 1 in your example), you could do this for example through:

```
static IEnumerable<double> Multiply( double[] left, double[] right ) {
  if ( left == null ) {
    throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof(left));
  }
  if ( right == null ){
    throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof(right));
  }

  var largest = left.Length > right.Length ? left : right;
  var smallest = left.Length > right.Length ? right : left;
  return smallest.Select( ( value, idx ) => value * largest[idx] )
    .Concat( largest.Skip( largest.Length - smallest.Length ) );
}
```

This would give you an `IEnumerable<double>` result back as part of the function, and you could then use it in this way:

```
public static void Main( string[] args ) {
  var array1 = new double[10] { 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
  var array2 = new double[5] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };

  var multiplication = Multiply( array1, array2 );
  foreach ( var item in multiplication ) {
    Console.WriteLine( item );
  }

  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Now, when looking into your original code, lets check some parts that where problematic in your version

```
double[] array3 = new double[10];
```

Declaring the `array3` to a fixed size makes your code quite vulnerable, namely if `array2` or `array1` changes in length, the result size would also change? In my example, in is more dynamic, as it depends on the largest array of the two.

```
int counter = 0;
// ...
if (counter <= k)
```

you define a counter to be null, but it is never incremented in the shared code, because of that your code should have crashed when hitting `array2[c]` where `c` has a value larger than the largest index in `array2`, which kinda explains why it only goes till `20`

```
foreach (int c in array1)
{
    foreach(int k in array2)
```

`foreach` will set the variable `c` and `k` respectively to the next value of `array1` and `array2` upon each iteration, but in your code you are using it more as an indexer, so you should have used the. Furthermore, you are iterating a `double[]` and define the variable as `int`, that could give very confusing results, so you would have been easier of using

```
for (var c = 0; c < array1.Length; c++) 
{
  for (var k = 0; k < array2.Length; k++)
  {
```

And now you can use them as indexes.

And the last one is that you where looping `array3` using foreach inside the first `foreach` loop (thus repeating your iteration), while using `c` as an index for your array while it should have been `j` variable.

Now if you fix all these points you get something like Melchia's answer, but that is also a fragile one, for example, if you would switch `array1` and `array2` your code won't give the expected output anymore